# Basic authentication required while accessing hazelcast rest api

Tags: caching, hazelcast

I am trying to use hazelcast rest api (hazelcast version 3.9.1) to gather caching information. I am exposing Rest endpoint in my application (e.g. http://localhost:8080/cache/info) using which the caching information will get collected (using hazelcast rest api e.g. /cache/localinfo) but ever time I hit the endpoint it pop up "Authentication Required" dialog and entering same credential which I used to set group config name and password doesn't work. 
**I am wondering how to first disable authentication (if possible). 
If not what credential it is looking for ? Shouldn't it be same what is being used to setup group config name and password while configuration hazelcast ?** e.g.                           `Config config = new Config(); 
config.getGroupConfig().setName("hazel-instance"); config.getGroupConfig().setPassword("password");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hazelcast doesn't offer the possibility to secure the REST API by using credentials. Hazelcast is not designed to be open to the public internet. If you want to have it for internal authentication we recommend to put nginx in front of the Hazelcast REST API and use a proxy mechanism.

Anyhow the REST API is considered a legacy API for situations where the programming language doesn't have a native client. The REST API doesn't know about the internal partitioning and therefore will not offer best possible performance.